# How can I get $cordovaDialogs.alert to show until internet connection is reestablished?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using $cordovaDialogs.alert to show a message when my app goes offline, this works fine, but it only displays the alert one time. When the user clicks ok on the alert they can continue to use the app which is not what I want. How can I get the alert to continue to popup until back online.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
// Handle the offline event

$cordovaDialogs.alert('Unable to connect to internet', 'No Connection', 'Try Again')
.then(function() {
  // callback success
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
document.addEventListener("online", onLine, false);

var connected = true;

function onOffline() {
connected = false;
// Handle the offline event
showOfflineAlert();
}

function onLine() {
connected = true;
}

function showOfflineAlert() {
$cordovaDialogs.alert('Unable to connect to internet', 'No Connection', 'Try Again')
.then(function() {
  // callback success
  if(!connected) {
    showOfflineAlert();
  }
});
```